# Kendo window disable maximize on double-click

Tags: kendo-ui, window, double-click, maximize, kendo-window

Plunkr: http://plnkr.co/edit/LoMmQ3y4snPrELJz9ZSq?p=preview

Can anyone help me on how to disable maximization of the window by double-clicking on its title? I tried to disable the dblclick event with the following code, but it doesn't seem to work.

```
$(document).on('dblclick','.k-window-titlebar',function(e){
  e.preventDefault();
  console.log('dblclick');
  return false;
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not a nice solution but might work, try toggling back to the previous size:

```
// Window definition
var win = $("#win1").kendoWindow({
    width: "300px",
    height: "100px",
    title: "Window 1",
    actions: []
}).data("kendoWindow");

$(document).on('dblclick','.k-window-titlebar',function(e){
  // Restore old size
  win.toggleMaximization();
});
```

Comment: Have a look at @Alex' answer which appears to fix the issue directly

Comment: It does not work on IE 11. There is an effect moving the dialog.

Answer (score 5):

```
// Window definition
var win = $("#win1").kendoWindow({
    width: "300px",
    height: "100px",
    title: "Window 1",
    actions: [],
    **resizable: false**
}).data("kendoWindow");
```

`resizable: false` - Will prevent from maximizing the window.

Comment: What if I want the window to be resizable, but not maximizing on titlebar double click?

Answer (score 1):

The following code worked for me:

```
   // Window definition
var win = $("#win1").kendoWindow({
    width: "300px",
    height: "100px",
    title: "Window 1",
    actions: []
}).data("kendoWindow");

win.wrapper.children('.k-window-titlebar:first-child')
                       .dblclick(function (e) {                           
                           e.preventDefault();
                           return false;
                        });
```

Try this: http://plnkr.co/edit/kAhw2A?p=preview

Comment: This is probably the best option while still retaining the ability to resize a window if necessary